# On a users click, load a block of javascript into page

Tags: javascript, html

I am adding a third party comment plugin on my html pages. The plugin slows down the pageload somewhat due to the number of connections the page makes to load the comment plugin.

The comment plugin will be contained within a div.

I would like to delay the loading of the comment javascript until a visitor clicks a 'add/read comments' button/link.

The language for the page is html5. I want to preferably, if possible, keep my pages as .html
The pages are html5 and css3.

my ccs3 and html5 knowledge is average. my javascript knowledge is poor. all other languages i haven't a clue about.

I was going to have the 'add/read comments' button/link, load up a duplicate page with the third party comment plugin loaded, but felt this was a messy way of doing this, as well as adding more time (another pageload then the plugin script) for the user to wait before being able to comment.

I don't want this comment plugin loading at all, not even in the background, until the user clicks the button. The reason for this, is because I don't want the user to see any indication of the page hanging/still loading, when the page load is complete without the comment plugin visable.

I sincerely hope this makes sense for someone to follow.

Answers will be much appreciated.
Thankyou for your time.

The following is the code livefyre gave me to insert into my html..

```
<div id="SPLUG"> <--- that is the div i am surrounding the comment plugin in


<div id="livefyre-comments"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://zor.livefyre.com/wjs/v3.0/javascripts/livefyre.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
    var articleId = fyre.conv.load.makeArticleId(null);
    fyre.conv.load({}, [{
        el: 'livefyre-comments',
        network: "livefyre.com",
        siteId: "xxxxxx",
        articleId: articleId,
        signed: false,
        collectionMeta: {
            articleId: articleId,
            url: fyre.conv.load.makeCollectionUrl(),
        }
    }], function() {});
}());
</script>
<!-- END: Livefyre Embed -->


</div>
```

Comment: which type of comment plugin? or where is its code?

Comment: What do you normally do to initialise the plugin? Just include a javascript element in the page? Or do you also have to call an initialisation function for it within your own javascript (`commentSystem.initialise()` or similar)?

Comment: Are you using jQuery? if not then I highly recommend it to learn and use it.

Comment: @AspiringAqib the comment plugin is provided by livefyre

Comment: @Beejamin usually have the javascript within the html page.

Comment: @AdilMughal no jquery but would be willing to learn the basics if thats all i needed to learn for this.

Comment: @Mel alright see my example below without jQuery

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically inserting external JavaScript to web pages when click on a button:

```
<button onclick="addScript()">Click</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function addScript() {
        var headTag = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         
        var newScript = document.createElement('script');
        newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
        newScript.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js';
        headTag.appendChild(newScript);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: could you break down what the above is doing please?

Comment: @Mel: the above addScript() function simply creates a script element and append it to head element of web page, you may want to set newScript.src to your external JavaScript link

Comment: I have included the livefyre block of code above in my original post.
I did move it (just the javascript portion) into a file named lifyre.js then put your example in the html, replacing

newScript.src = 'http://code.jquery  etc...

with

newScript.src = 'js/lifyre.js';

which didn't work. I really have no idea what i'm meant to be doing here. So sorry for not being able to follow your instructions.. help?  (edit because cat sat on edge of keyboard as still typing)

Answer (score 0):

It's not really difficult. Defer loading of JavaScript or external stuff is now needed for faster page loads. For example, there are Facebook/twitter plugins which I wanted to load once my page is loaded so one way to do is to initialize external plugins loading in [window.onload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) or $(window).load in case of jQuery.

In your case, in the comment button onclick event, load the JavaScript of external plugin. What we typically do is manipulate the elements using Document Object Model (DOM).

As an example, I want to load an iframe on button click:

```
<input type="button" id="btnComment" onclick="createframe();" style="height:50px; width:120px;" value="Click Me!" />
<div id="container"></div>


function createframe() {
    var i = document.createElement("iframe");
    i.src = "http://www.adilmughal.com";
    i.scrolling = "auto";
    i.frameborder = "0";
    i.width = "90%";
    i.height = "220px";
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(i);
}
```

What this will do is create a new iframe element with any src URL and append as container's child.

Output and code can also be viewed on http://jsfiddle.net/adilmughal/ZJZn7/

Comment: I understand (i think) how this is working. My understanding on this, is that you are suggesting I put the livefyre code into another html, which will be loaded inside a frame on the pages I want the comment block to appear on.

If so, I have a concern/question.. the comment plugin is article dependent. Each different page will load comments only relating to that page....

Comment: ... I think livefyre uses the page url to pull comments with as an identifier. wouldn't using the external html file (containing the livefyre js) in the iframe cause it to identify the wrong url? Which means i would have to use multiple external htmls for the iframes?

Sorry for my lack of knowledge here.

Comment: No it's not necessary to keep it separate... my whole point was to show how you can manipulate DOM on any event...

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a look at the liveFire docs, and it looks like it should be easy enough to initialise it on click, rather than as the page loads.

However, liveFyre actually initialises as soon as it can - rather than playing nice and waiting for the page to be ready. This is very likely the reason it slows down your page load. Does your liveFyre code look like this?

```
<!-- START: LiveFyre Embed -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://livefyre.com/wjs/javascripts/livefyre.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  fyre = LF({
    site_id: xxxxx,
    version: '1.0'
  });
</script>
<!-- END: LiveFyre Embed -->
```

If it does, try changing it to:

```
<!-- START: LiveFyre Embed -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://livefyre.com/wjs/javascripts/livefyre.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    fyre = LF({
      site_id: xxxxx,
      version: '1.0'
    });
  });
</script>
<!-- END: LiveFyre Embed -->
```

This should just make livefyre wait until the page is interactive before it tries to initialise. It may not help enough (or at all), but it's a safe and easy option to try first. If it doesn't help enough, post back, and we'll pursue your 'initialise on click' option.

--- UPDATE ---

Based on your comments with the code snippet, try this (I think the comment has been a little bit mangled - hopefully you can translate this over OK:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="zor.livefyre.com/wjs/v3.0/javascripts/livefyre.js">
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(function(){
    var articleId = fyre.conv.load.makeArticleId(null);
    fyre.conv.load({}, [{
      el: 'livefyre-comments',
      network: "livefyre.com",
      siteId: "xxxxxx",
      articleId: articleId,
      signed: false,
      collectionMeta: {
        articleId: articleId,
        url: fyre.conv.load.makeCollectionUrl()
        }
      }]
      , function() {});
  })();    
</script>
```

Again, the idea is just to wait for the page to be interactive before trying to initialise. Let us know what happens!

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://zor.livefyre.com/wjs/v3.0/javascripts/livefyre.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
    var articleId = fyre.conv.load.makeArticleId(null);
    fyre.conv.load({}, [{
        el: 'livefyre-comments',
        network: "livefyre.com",
        siteId: "xxxxxx",
        articleId: articleId,
        signed: false,
        collectionMeta: {
            articleId: articleId,
            url: fyre.conv.load.makeCollectionUrl(),
        }
    }], function() {});
}());
</script>

The above is what livefyre gave me to insert into the page